# ListView Adapter Async Manipulation

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a Custom ListView [this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/ObservableListView.java) is the ListView I am using that shows some data on the screen, Pretty simple. Now I need to theme the shown data view. the way I do this is by saving a `key, value` to SQLite adapter, I don't want to use SharedPrefs, This takes a long process to read over 120+ keys! and lags the UI a lot so I thought lets make an async `setBackground` so here is what I put together.

`public static HashMap<String, String> lruCache = new HashMap<>();`

I cache all the keys in a hashset

and then I made a method that checks if the key exists if not it gets the key using AsyncTask

```
public static void setBackgroundColor(View view, String key, String defaultValue) {
    String val = lruCache.get(key);
    if (val != null) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(ThemeUtils.parseColor(val));
        return;
    }
    new AsyncBackgroundColor(view).execute(key, defaultValue);
}

public static class AsyncBackgroundColor extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    WeakReference<View> view;

    AsyncBackgroundColor(View view) {
        this.view = new WeakReference<>(view);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
        return ThemeUtils.getColor(strings[0], strings[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer color) {
        view.get().setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}
```

and this is how my `getColor` method works.

```
public static int getColor(String str, String defaultValue) {
    ThemeDatabaseManager lynxDatabaseHelper = new ThemeDatabaseManager(LynxBase.getApplicationContext()).open();
    return ThemeUtils.parseColor(lynxDatabaseHelper.getString(str, defaultValue));
}
```

It gets the string from my SQlite database and parses it to an int. This is my `getString` method

```
public String getString(String key, String defaultValue) {
    String cachedValue = ThemeDatabaseCache.lruCache.get(key);
    if (cachedValue != null) {
        return cachedValue;
    }
    if (!database.isOpen()) open();
    String[] columns = new String[]{ThemeDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, ThemeDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE};
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            do {
                if (!(cursor.getColumnCount() <= 1)) {
                    String k = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ThemeDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE));
                    String value = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ThemeDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE));
                    if (k.equals(key)) {
                        cursor.close();
                        if (database.isOpen()) database.close();
                        ThemeDatabaseCache.lruCache.put(key, defaultValue);
                        return value;
                    }
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    insertOrUpdate(key, defaultValue);
    if (database.isOpen()) database.close();
    return defaultValue;
}
```

I fetch all the SQLite colums and loop until I find the correct key and then return that how ever if the value doesn't exist I just insert the default value into the SQLite database, that way I always end up with a key the other time.

The problem happens here. It doesn't theme all the tabs in the adapter.

[image]

as you can see It only themed the 3rd adapter item, But when I scroll up and down, the position changes. So It wont change 3rd its gonna be 5th and you get the point, Does anyone know how I can resolve this? I am been debugging this for about 5 days now, Tried all sorts of stuff can't seem to fix it.

The black is what all of the item is suppose to look like once the `setBackgroundColor` is done. The white is the default color applied using XML Layout.

This is how I call it on my adapter.

```
public final View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){\
    ...
    view = inflate(R.layout.my_view, viewGroup, false);
    setBackground(view);
    ...
}
```

and my class is extending a custom class that I made that extends `BaseAdapter` if that helps!

This is what I have tried according to the answer.

```
public static void setBackgroundColor(BaseAdapter baseAdapter, View view, String key, String defaultValue) {
    String val = lruCache.get(key);
    if (val != null) {
        Log.wtf("Lynx", "background set using cached Color.");
        view.setBackgroundColor(ThemeUtils.parseColor(val));
        baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return;
    }
    new AsyncBackgroundColor(baseAdapter, view).execute(key, defaultValue);
}
```

..

```
public static class AsyncBackgroundColor extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    WeakReference<View> view;
    BaseAdapter baseAdapter;

    AsyncBackgroundColor(BaseAdapter baseAdapter, View view) {
        this.view = new WeakReference<>(view);
        this.baseAdapter = baseAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {

        return ThemeUtils.getColor(strings[0], strings[1]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer color) {
        Log.wtf("Lynx", "background set using async task.");
        view.get().setBackgroundColor(color);
        if(baseAdapter != null)
        baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

But It's still the same as before.

Here is the Catlog dump:

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that `getColor` gets called for all your items and returns the correct result? And the problem is just that the color returned is not reflected on the view ?

Comment: @113408 it gets called on all my items, Because I call it inside my recylerView where is set all the other objects. This works if I just set the color from the database and skip the async bit. But when I use async it doesn't work.

Comment: @113408 I will do some debugging and post the debug log on the post.

Comment: If I understand well, `setBackgroundColor` is a method within your `CustomAdapter` then why you pass it as an argument? I would use `this` to refer it and pass it to the `AsyncTask`

Comment: @113408 No It's not, Its a method in an outterclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works if I just set the color from the database and skip the
>   async bit. But when I use async it doesn't work.

This happens because your `AsyncTask` doesn't work on the **UIThread** and therefore when the result is back it doesn't `redraw` your items. To do so you need to notify the adapter that new elements are present using `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

From the code you shared, I guess you can just call it from your `postExecute`:

```
public static class AsyncBackgroundColor extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    WeakReference<View> view;
    WeakReference<Adapter> adapter;

    AsyncBackgroundColor(Adapter ad, View view) {
        this.view = new WeakReference<>(view);
        this.adapter = new WeakReference<>(ad);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer color) {
        view.get().setBackgroundColor(color);
        adapter.get().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Also on your `getString()` change this part:

```
if (k.equals(key)) {
                    cursor.close();
                    if (database.isOpen()) database.close();
                    ThemeDatabaseCache.lruCache.put(key, value);
                    return value;
                }
```

Comment: I actually can't access my `recyclerView` I only have access to the view objects. I can't update the adapter nor the layoutManager.

Comment: and if I have over 100 items, Its gonna call that piece of code 100 times, I don't see a way my code isn't called on UIThread either since it's called on `onPostExecute`?

Comment: @SamzSakerz the purpose of using `AsyncTask` as you mentioned is to not block your UI while loading the stuff from cache/DB. So when the result is back `onCreateViewHolder` is not called again and therefore your color doesn't get applied.

Comment: Well my issue is I can't access the recylerView ref, Since the workspace I am working on is limited, I only have access to the `getView` on the adapter

Comment: Oops, I actually made a mistake on the question I am not actually using a recylerview I forgot I switched my code to https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/ObservableListView.java, So Its actually a ListVIew. I will update the question

Comment: I updated the question but yeah, I can't access the ListView reference, Since I don't want to pass it to my adapter.

Comment: @SamzSakerz have you tried `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on the `setBackgroundColor` ?

Comment: No I did not, Since I am only passing the view. I don't think I am allowed to pass the adapter.

Comment: Are you able to share the code on how you setup the adapter and how you call setBackgroundColor ? if so please update the question

Comment: I am afraid I can't show you how I setup the adapter. but basically this is what I do for the `setBackgroundColor` part. I just call it on my custom layout on the `getView` method.

Comment: Updated the question, showing how I call the setBackground

Comment: I am gonna try to pass `this` to my setBackground method as `BaseAdapter` and try to call `notifyDatasetChanged` inside `onPostExecute` and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested just now, and it didnt work.

Comment: Updated post. .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188555/discussion-between-113408-and-samzsakerz).

Answer (score 1):

Just as a complement. Instead of fetching your whole database and match `ThemeDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE`, you should change your query to only get the entries you are interested in. It would speed up your operations and avoid delays.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, I am still new to the SQLite api, can you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I haven't tested but this should work. Replace `Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);` with `Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, ThemeDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, key, null, null, null);`. Basically you are telling the database to only get the entries with a title that matches `key`.

Comment: I see. I am guessing I still need the loop?

Comment: Actually you probably won't need it anymore.

Comment: Hmm, Will take a look thanks. Upvoted for your efforts.